# Simulate the execution of two functions at the same time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have the following two functions:

```
loadTop(); 
loadBottom();
```

Basically one loads the top portion of the page and the other loads the bottom portion of the page. The loadTop function includes asynchronous work. To ensure that loading is as visually seamless as possible, I want to see if there’s a way to execute both functions at the same time, but only have loadBottom() running in the background and not actually complete until loadTop() is finished.

I’ve read that javascript doesn't really support multithreading, but there’s a way to simulate it on a single thread using asynchronous callback functions. Can anyone provide an example of how to do this as it pertains to the above two functions?

Comment: What do `loadTop` and `loadBottom` do? How are they defined?

Comment: And what's wrong with just executing them the way you have it, is something asynchronous going on? What specifically is loading, and from where ?

Comment: loadTop and loadBottom load the divs, CSS, and click events for the corresponding portions of the page.

Comment: @adeneo, by the time loadTop() is complete, I essentially want all the computation for loadBottom() already done so the bottom will display a bit faster.

Comment: What computations? The CSS and JS etc? That can't be computed before that part of the DOM is there.

Comment: It's difficult to give you a clear answer without seeing the definitions of `loadTop` and `loadBottom`.

Comment: Each function traverses a predefined html node, so the problem isn't that the necessary part of the DOM doesn't already exist.

Comment: You're not being very clear, traverses how, is it asynchronous, what are you waiting for ?

Comment: @FionaCat86 Is `loadTop` asynchronous? Are you doing some kind of AJAX or anything? If they're both synchronous, there's no much you can do, especially if they both touch the DOM.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes loadTop is asynchronous. Will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `loadTop` return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and only have `loadBottom` render when that Promise is resolved.

```js
function loadTop() {
  console.log('Top: Loading...');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Simulate loading some data
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Top: complete');
      document.getElementById('top').innerHTML = 'Top: Loaded';
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}

function loadBottom(promise) {
  console.log('Bottom: Loading...');
  // Simulate loading some data
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Bottom: Waiting for top...');
    // Wait for the `loadTop` promise to complete
    promise.then(function() {
      document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = 'Bottom: Loaded';
    });
  }, 500);
}

loadBottom(loadTop());
```

```html
<h1 id="top"></h1>
<h1 id="bottom"></h1>
```

It's also possible to do this using a callback mechanism but things get much more complicated. You need to share a function between the two functions. First, `loadBottom` needs to create the function which will be called when top completes. Next, you need to pass that function back to `loadTop`. Theoretically, with this setup, `loadTop` may finish before `loadBottom` and the callback will be called prematurely. This could be mitigated by implementing an event listener.

```js
function loadTop(cb) {
  console.log('Top: Loading...');
  // Simulate loading some data
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Top: complete');
    document.getElementById('top').innerHTML = 'Top: Loaded';
    cb();
  }, 3000);
}

function loadBottom() {
  // Will get called when `loadTop` completes
  function onLoadTopComplete() {
    document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = 'Bottom: Loaded';
    console.log('Bottom: complete');
  }
  
  console.log('Bottom: Loading...');
  // Simulate loading some data
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Bottom: Waiting for top...');
  }, 500);
  
  return onLoadTopComplete;
}

loadTop(loadBottom());
```

```html
<h1 id="top"></h1>
<h1 id="bottom"></h1>
```

Comment: Unless something async is going on in `loadTop` it would be the same as just calling one before the other ?

Comment: @adeneo "I want to see if there’s a way to execute both functions at the same time, but only have loadBottom() running in the background and not actually complete until loadTop() is finished." To me, that implies that `loadTop` does some asynchronous work. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, Mike, your intuition is correct. loadTop performs asynchronous work.

Comment: @FionaCat86 Cool. Then you can absolutely utilize a Promise to allow `loadBottom` to run while waiting on `loadTop` to complete as well as only finishing `loadBottom` after `loadTop` has finished.

Comment: @Mike, curious if there be a way to do this without the use of the Promise object, I guess by just using vanilla callbacks and function definitions? Want to get a full understanding of how this is working.

Comment: @FionaCat86 Sure, check out my edit. There's a number of ways of syncing up asynchronous events but Promises are definitely the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like that you set an indicator and continuously check it whether it's been changed.

```
function loadTop() {
console.log('Top: Loading...');
// As Finished go invoke the callBack loadTopFinished
loadTopFinished();
}
function loadTopFinished(){
  indicator = 1;
}
function loadBottom(promise) {
  console.log('Bottom: Loading...');
  // Simulate loading some data
  loadCheck();
}
function loadCheck(){
  if(1 == indicator){
    // It's done.
    console.log("Bottom: Loaded");
  }
  // Haven't Done, then do something continuously in loadBottom(Alike)
  setTimeout(loadCheck,1000);

}
var indicator = 0;
loadTop();
loadBottom();
```

Or if you want to create an event loop, then something like this

Though you could use ways like this:

```
function TheloopHere(){
  loadBottom();
  while(true){
    if(loadTopCheck()){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function loadTopCheck(){
    // Some loading asychonouly here
    // After Loading for top
    return;
}
```

Or you can use a post-function callback to finish up the work in loadBtm, by calling it after the loadTop

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a way to avoid using the global variable here (indicator)? Also, when will indicator ever be "SOMEHOW"?

Comment: just some random value for instance it's SOMEWHAT, a typo here.

Comment: you can use indicator in other ways as a new object here as to define the prototype of something, and later check up whether the object has been declared. Btw, asynchronous callback functions are just run the same way as your own invokes because you can see it when you're debugging. It's just invoked by some self-looping functions inside the browser.

Comment: there's not actually some multi-processing work here, all functions are working inside one process, as there's just a simulated time and event based loop checker going on to implement timeOuts or time intervals etc. Still, there is some ways to use multi-processing ways in Javascript, but that would be running on node.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 features then you can use ES6 promise,
 [GO Through Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Otherwise you can pass Callback to one of your function lets say load top and on that call back you can lead your load bottom function